# Using session_set_cookie_params destroying the session data

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to implement session_set_cookie_params in my php code and it is causing issues with session_id and destroying session data. The session_id is regenerating on page refresh or when navigating to other pages and as a result not allowing me to login. Here is my code:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$secure = TRUE;  
$httponly = TRUE;  
$samesite = 'lax';

if ( PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300 ) {
    session_set_cookie_params([0, '/; samesite='.$samesite, $domain, $secure, $httponly]);
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params([
        'lifetime' => 0,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $domain,
        'secure' => $secure,
        'httponly' => $httponly,
        'samesite' => $samesite
    ]);
}

session_start();
```

When I commented out the above code for session_set_cookie_params, session is working fine and session_id stays same on page refresh and when navigating.

Could anyone please help me narrow down the issue?

Comment: Anybody up for help on it?